# Rotate camera to face object without messing up lat lon values

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

The code I'm using to control my camera works by moving a vector(camera.target) and then setting the camera to look at that vector. In this case camera.lookAt( camera.target );. The onDocumentMouseMove function calculates a longitude and latitude and this helps to set the camera.target x, y, and z values. Below is an example of how things work. Pressing any key will cause the camera to rotate to an object but if you do that the next time you go to move the camera by dragging the mouse the camera will automatically jump to the last position before the keystroke. This is because in order for the mouse to move the camera it has to keep track of the lat and lon. So what I'm having issues with is calculating the new lat lon position after the keystroke. I was thinking if the target x,y,z values can be calculated from the lon and lat than it would stand to reason that the lat and lon could be reverse calculated from the x,y,z, values. Unfortunately the math is beyond my means. I have added a bounty to this issue. Any help would be very much appreciated. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgRXJz

```
        var spriteImg, material, geometry;
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
        var fov = 70,
        texture_placeholder,
        isUserInteracting = false,
        onMouseDownMouseX = 0, onMouseDownMouseY = 0,
        lon = 0, onMouseDownLon = 0,
        lat = 0, onMouseDownLat = 0,
        phi = 0, theta = 0;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            var container;

            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100 );
            camera.target = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
            stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
            stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0125fd} );
            geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50, 3, 3);
            blue1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            blue1.position.set(200,100,200);
            scene.add(blue1);
            blue1.lookAt( camera.position );

            blue2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            blue2.position.set(-200,-100,-200);
            blue2.lookAt( camera.position );
            scene.add(blue2);

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            isUserInteracting = true;

            onPointerDownPointerX = event.clientX;
            onPointerDownPointerY = event.clientY;

            onPointerDownLon = lon;
            onPointerDownLat = lat;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
            if ( isUserInteracting ) {
                lon = ( event.clientX - onPointerDownPointerX ) * 0.3 + onPointerDownLon;
                lat = ( onPointerDownPointerY - event.clientY ) * 0.3 + onPointerDownLat;
            }
        }

        function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {
            isUserInteracting = false;
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
            update();
        }   

        function update()
        {           
            stats.update();
        }

        function render() {

            lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
            phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
            theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );

            camera.target.x = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
            camera.target.y = 500 * Math.cos( phi );
            camera.target.z = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );

            camera.lookAt( camera.target );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate that latitude and longitude from the x,y,z coordinates you inverse your methods. Please see [updated code-pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azzrEP) for demo.

#### Original:

```
lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );

camera.target.x = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
camera.target.y = 500 * Math.cos( phi );
camera.target.z = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );
```

#### Inverse:

*Snippet taken from the [original code-pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgRXJz), found on the `document.body.onkeydown` action event listener within the `update()` method -- modified this method in the demo with the following code*

```
//Since you are looking at a given shape on keypress, decided to inverse from that
//shape's position.
camera.lookAt( blue1.position );
//Added the following four lines of code
phi = Math.acos((blue1.position.y)/500);
theta = Math.acos((blue1.position.x)/(500 * Math.sin(phi)))
lon = THREE.Math.radToDeg(theta);
lat = 90-THREE.Math.radToDeg(phi);
```

#### Finer details in algebra

Seeing as how I always got docked points in school for only showing solutions, here is how I got to the inverse/solving for latitude and longitude from x, y, and z

Let **x**, **y**, and **z** represent your given viewpoint (`camera.target.x` or `<object>.position.x`, etc).

Let `phi` = Φ, `theta` = Θ

**Solving for Θ**

1. x = 500 * sin (Φ) * cos(Θ)
2. x/(500 * sin(Φ)) = 500 * sin (Φ) * cos(Θ) / (500 * sin(Φ))
3. x/(500 * sin(Φ)) = cos(Θ)
4. arccos(x/(500 * sin(Φ))) = arccos(cos(Θ))
5. arccos(x/(500 * sin(Φ))) = Θ

**Solving for Φ**

1. y = 500 * cos(Φ)
2. y/500 = 500 * cos(Φ) / 500
3. y/500 = cos(Φ)
4. arccos(y/500) = arccos(cos(Φ))
5. arccos(y/500) = Φ

**Solving for `lon`**

1. Θ = degToRad(lon)
2. radToDeg(Θ) = degToRad(degToRad(lon))
3. radToDeg(Θ) = lon

**solving for `lat`**

1. Φ = degToRad( 90 - lat );
2. radToDeg(Φ) = radToDeg(degToRad( 90 - lat ))
3. radToDeg(Φ) = 90 - lat
4. radToDeg(Φ) - 90 = 90 - lat - 90
5. radToDeg(Φ) - 90 = -lat
6. -1*(radToDeg(Φ) - 90) = -1*(-lat)
7. -radToDeg(Φ + 90 = lat
8. 90 - radToDeg(Φ) = lat
9. 90 - radToDeg(Φ) = lat

Comment: Thanks, a bug appeared with camera position, you can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/42qeojs0/ (uncomment the 3 lines of camera position at the end of init)

Comment: Yes, I changed the origin but why this should affect your calcul ?

Comment: If you uncomment the lines, when you move the camera on the first time, it doesn't start moving from the square's position (but after it works well)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I spent some time looking into it. The issue is you are changing the origin and that changes the Math I used to answer this question (the trigonometry changes in converting the spherical coordinates to rectangular). You need to account for the change in X, Y, and Z at the origin, if you are going to manually change it. The lat/lon calculation needs to be reworked as the values are incorrect because the origin is not at 0,0,0 and X,Y, and Z are no longer the length of a triangle side, so to speak. That's a more complex question, demanding a more complex answer.

Comment: Cartesian coordinate system for three dimensions, not Rectangular (Cartesian coordinate for two dimensions). If I get some free time I'll take another look -- I could see how answering that here (although beyond the scope) could still benefit this post.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I really need to make this code work. Your example has been very useful for me as I integrated it into my project, now I really want to fix this last bug. It would be amazing if you could take a look :) Thanks again !

Comment: I created a new post related to this problem, you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963176/three-js-pov-camera-look-around-bug

Answer (score 0):

`camera.lookAt(yourObject.position);`//?

Supposing i got you right and the question is this part: "a way to rotate the camera to look at an object"

BTW I think it's confusing in your code how you both modify camera.target and then also call camera.lookAt. I think when you call lookAt you don't need to modify the target, and vice versa.

Comment: If you check out the codepen example you'll see this code allows you to click and drag with the mouse to rotate the camera. In the onDocumentMouseDown and onDocumentMouseMove functions there is a lon and a lat variable that is used to create the phi and the theta. The phi and theta are then used to set the xyz values of the target. And than the camera is set to look at those coordinates. What I should have mentioned is I can use camera.lookAt(yourObject.position); to rotate the camera But if I do the camera will jump to the last know lon lat the next time I click the screen.

Comment: I did check your example to begin with but did not really understand what the idea was. Actually still don't get what you want .. you already know how to rotate the cam to an object (which is the question title). What would you like to happen when the user clicks after that?

Comment: Ran out of room on the last comment. Lol. So what I'm looking for is a way to calculate the lon and lat position of the object I want to look at Or a way to calculate the lon lat of the camera after it has been rotated. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I was thinking if the target x,y,z values can be calculated from the lon and lat than it would stand to reason that the lat and lon could be reverse calculated from the x,y,z, values. Unfortunately the math is beyond my means.

Comment: Sorry it seems you responded before I could finish writing back. I'm kind of a slow typer.

Comment: I'm going to update the codepen to better demonstrate my issue.

Comment: Ok here is an updated version of the example. Pressing any key will cause the camera to rotate to the object but if you do that the next time you go to move the camera by dragging the mouse the camera will automatically jump to the last position before the keystroke. This is because in order for the mouse to move the camera it has to keep track of the lat and lon. So what I'm having issues with is calculating the new lat lon position after the keystroke. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgRXJz

Comment: ok thanks, the updated example and explanation at least make the issue much clearer.

one way to solve would be to use relative movement when you handle the mouse. this way it would not matter if the camera was rotated with the keyboard in the middle too. i'd consider that.

i'm sure there is a way to calculate also the way you want but i did not understand fully how you deal with the mouse rotating in the first place enough to know how yet. need sleep now, will look again tomorrow if have time.

Comment: did you consider the idea of switching to relative movement? just calculate the camera rotation relative to the previous camera position.

Comment: Yea I was thinking about that last night but there's a lot of other code thatls dependent on the lat lon system. Finding a way to calculate the lat lon from the camera.target xyz would be ideal.